# CLGeocoder bug on CoreLocation SDK

Tags: swift, uikit, core-location

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude: coord.longitude)) { [weak self] placeMarks, error in
      print("PLACEMARKSFIRST:")
      print(placeMarks?.first)
      self?.geoCodeCounter += 1
       
      guard let place = placeMarks?.first else {
        self?.selectionSubject.accept(nil)
        self?.geoCodeAddress()
        return
      } 

print("PLACEMARKSFIRST:")
      print(placeMarks?.first)
      self?.geoCodeCounter += 1
       
      guard let place = placeMarks?.first else {
        self?.selectionSubject.accept(nil)
        self?.geoCodeAddress()
        return
      }
      print("PLACE:")
      print(place)
      print(place.administrativeArea)
      print(place.subAdministrativeArea)
      print(place.locality)
      print(place.subLocality)
      print(place.thoroughfare)
      print(place.subThoroughfare)
      self?.geoAdministrativeArea = place.administrativeArea ?? ""
      self?.geoSubAdministrativeArea = place.subAdministrativeArea ?? ""
      self?.geoLocality = place.locality ?? ""
      self?.geoSubLocality = place.subLocality ?? ""
      self?.geoThoroughfare = place.thoroughfare ?? ""
      self?.geoSubThoroughfare = place.subThoroughfare ?? ""
```

**DEBUG CODES:**

> PLACE: Darüşşafaka Cd. 5/2, Darüşşafaka Cd. 5/2, 34457 Sarıyer İstanbul, Türkiye @ <+41.12570667,+29.02811721> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+41.12570100,+29.02817000> radius 70.68', center:<+41.12570100,+29.02817000>, radius:70.68m)
>
> Optional("İstanbul")
> Optional("Sarıyer")
> Optional("Sarıyer")
> Optional("Çamlıtepe")
> Optional("Darüşşafaka Cd.")
> Optional("5/2")

As you see above there is a conflict between the locality inside place and the response that place.locality returns. Locality must be "Darüşşafaka". How can I fix this?

Is it about a bug in CLGeocoder library?

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not a bug even its not a mistake that you can fix.

You get what the `locality` value is at the location specified on the Apple maps database

If you see the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark/1423507-locality) you will see :

> If the placemark location is Apple’s headquarters, for example, the value for this property would be the string “Cupertino”.

The locality value of Apple headquarters is Cupertino because it is expressed that way on maps.

As a result, if the locality value is defined as `Sarıyer` in the coordinates you entered, there is no way to change it.

You may need to check and manipulate other properties to get the value you want